# Can i view hidden data in an adobe acrobat pdf file?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have an adobe acrobat pdf file.

I have adobe acrobat pro dc.

Does acrobat pdf have hidden information / metadata? If so, how do I view it?

Comment: What type of hidden information are you looking for? You can view PDF details by going to File -> Properties. See more on Adobe Help website - [PDF properties and metadata](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-properties-metadata.html)

Comment: You can quite literally embed anything in a PDF file. It has a functon for that. This is how illustrator files work.

Comment: @AndrewH, can i find a list of the hidden data somehow?  I'm not looking *for* anything in particular, just wondering what is there!

Comment: there are command line tools for this on mac and linux. here is a linux resource:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/401114/which-is-the-best-pdf-metadata-viewer-for-ubuntu  one thing mentioned there is exiftool, which you can get on mac with 'brew install exiftool'